# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in sqlite_step(statement)

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite, crash, exc-bad-access

I am using sqlite database for iphone app. but its crash on "while loop" line while retrieving data from database sometimes.

```
-(void)GetMethod
{

    NSString *query = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM errorlogs"];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;    
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String],-1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) **// EXC_BAD_ACCESS ON THIS LINE**
        { 
            char *uid1 = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
            NSString *uid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",uid1];
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

why I am getting this EXC_BAD_ACCESS on while loop.

[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either `sqlite3_step(statement)` or `SQLITE_ROW` is not initialized, or has already been released. When it runs the equality check on the nonexistent object, it throws EXE_BAD_ACCESS.

Are you returning any rows?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am just using the above code mentioned in my question. so sqlite3_step(statement) is initialized and sqlite_row is a constant. And they are not released yet.

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM errorlogs` return any rows? If errorlogs is empty, you could be comparing against nothing, which would throw an error.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the FMDB framework, it helped me a lot in my project.

Here's the link: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb 
Give it a look if you can ;)

Comment: Is it different Database? if yes, I cannot migrate from one database to another for this error.

Comment: no, its just a wrapper to simplify the coding, that's pretty much it. plus its super easy to use. 
One thing try to enable the nszombies to track your error, just press alt + cmd + r and there's one checkbox saying "Enable Zombie Objects".

Comment: NSZombie is enabled on my project. but still it is throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS on that line.